# Concurrency Tests in Django

Tags: python, django, concurrency, django-testing, django-tests

Peace be upon all, I just started Django last month. I needed help running concurrency tests in Django, so what I've done is tried to write code that will prevent issues that arise due to lack of concurrency but what I  don't know is how to verify and test the code to see that it meets my expectations. What I want is to send multiple requests at the same time to see if the code works as expected.

The target function in views.py

```
def buy_animal(request):
  
context = {}

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = buys_animal(request.POST)
   
    
    if form.is_valid() == True or form.is_valid() == False:
        #return HttpResponse('asdasd')
        nm = request.POST['an_name']

        b = Animal.objects.filter(an_name = nm)
        #return HttpResponse("yo ")
        #nm = request.POST['an_name']
    
        qt = int(request.POST['qty'])
        if b.count() <= 0:
            return HttpResponse(str(b.count()) + " Sorry we're out of animals")
        else:
            try: 
                with transaction.atomic():
                        
                    b.select_for_update()
                    b = b[0]
                    #b.an_name = 'asd'
                    #b.save()
                   
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        Quality.objects.filter( animal = Animal.objects.filter(an_name = 'ringneck')[0] ).select_for_update()
                        c = Quality.objects.filter( animal = Animal.objects.filter(an_name = 'ringneck')[0] )[0]
                        c.rating = 'niece'
                        c.save()
             
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Database Error')           
                            
                   
             
            if b.qty - qt < 0:
                
                return HttpResponse("Sorry we don't have enough animals") 
                
            else: 
                    
                b.qty = b.qty - qt
                b.save()
                a = Buy_animal( an_name = nm, qty = qt, 
                buyer = MyUser.objects.filter(username = request.user.username)[0] )
                a.save()
                   
                   
                return HttpResponse('animal bought')
        
        
        
       
        
    else :
        
        form = buys_animal()
        context = {}
        context = {'form' : form}   

        return render(request, "buy_animal_form.html", context) 
            


else :
    
    form = buys_animal()
    context = {}
    context = {'form' : form}   

    return render(request, "buy_animal_form.html", context)
```

My models.py code can be found in the below repository
https://bitbucket.org/mab_786/django_models_code/src/master/models.py
`

Kindly ignore any stupid errors on my part as I just started with django.
Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate if someone could share the tests.py code to test such a situation. I didn't write this code as part of any project but to clear up my concepts